# Hacer que Scroll se baje automaticamente

Tags: php, javascript, html

Es que estoy haciendo un chat, pero el problema es que al enviar un mensaje el scroll debe irse hasta abajo, pero también deberia poderse ver los mensajes anteriores. Este es mi codigo en js:

```
function Scroll(){
document.getElementById('chat').scrollTop =document.getElementById('chat').scrollHeight;
setInterval(function(){Scroll();},1000);
```

}

Pero lo unico que hace es irse hasta abajo y al querer ver mensajes anteriores no deja

Comment: En su momento lo solucione poniendo un input hidden abajo del ultimo mensaje q se insertaba y le hacia un autofocus cada vez que se generaba un nuevo mensaje de esa forma siempre se iba abajo del chat y dsp te dejaba moverte a donde quieras

Comment: gracias me funciono

Comment: Excelente! Respondete vos mismo esta pregunta cpn la solucion asi podes ayudar a otra persona si tuvo el mismo inconveniente o tal vez otro ve tu codigo y te puede ayudar a mejorarlo